# TokenReplace on Web.Config

Tags: tfs, token, release, tokenize, release-management

I am using the TokenReplace task to replace some tokens in my web.config file before deployment (TFS 2015 Release Defintion).

The Release deployment complains:

```
##[error]Could not find files with glob [\\sevstfs\_work\2\a\_PublishedWebsites\Starlight\*.config].
```

However, I have confirmed that the file is and was, there.

My Environment variables in the definition are:
[image]

And my web.config tokens are here:
[image]

Any help appreciated.

thanks,

KS

Comment: Please share a screenshot your build definition. And which TokenReplace task do you use?

Comment: One from Colins ALM Corner

Answer (score 0):

I just tested the Replace Tokens task at website https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens, which works fine. You may check it.

Comment: Did you try the Replace Tokens task from the link I provided?